# Programming Language for Senior Citizens

Tags: programming-languages

I am looking for a programming language fit for senior citizens that is:

- easy to get into
- can be used to implement easy functions and concepts (for loops, maybe a plot, etc.).

The language should be very light on the syntax side. The performance in terms of speed etc. is irrelevant.

What I am looking for is a way for people in retirement who are tired of crossword puzzles to be able to code as a pastime.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Use Python.  It is by far the easiest language to learn.  There's a plethora of resources for learning, there are games to play while learning (codecombat), python is fun.

Answer (score 2):

I think there are good opportunities for learning a programming language e.g. also for seniors. I think "becoming familiar" with the programming language is important. E.g. seeing how it works (samel like "using crossword puzzles"):

**Programming language, which ist suitable for kids (and hence for seniors)**

- Kara - basic ideas of programming langauge will be provided here (
- [Scratch](https://scratch.mit.edu/)(visual programming language / Users of the site can create online projects using a block-like-interface)
- [Open roberta](https://lab.open-roberta.org/) (encourage kids and maybe seniors using robots e.g. Lego Mindstorms)
- Nepro programming language

**Programming for advanced people (search for pupils and kid programming)**

- SNAP! (blocks based educational graphical programming language)
- GameKit

**Maybe there are some seniors with little programming experience from the past (e.g. school) then I would use the "old" programming languages**

- Lisp
- Pascal

I would really recommend to start something easy and something visual, this helps seniors to understand how the algorithms working.